# Upgrading IntelliJ from Grails 1.1 to Grails 1.1.1

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I've recently upgraded from Grails 1.1 to Grails 1.1.1. I've updated my projects accordingly using "grails upgrade".

However, IntelliJ does not seem to have picked up the upgrade so when opening my Grails project I get the following dialog:

> Application has Grails version 1.1.1, but current Grails version is 1.1. Upgrade application?

How do I configure IntelliJ to use my Grails 1.1.1 installation rather than the older 1.1 installation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

1. **Configure grails-1.1.1 in IntelliJ.** From the menu bar, choose: File > New Project > Create project from scratch > Name your project and choose "Grails Application" as type > Next > Grails SDK > New > Choose the location of your Grails 1.1.1 installation.
2. **Configure your project to use Grails 1.1.1.** Open your project. From the menu bar, choose: File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Modules > Dependencies: Remove "grails-1.1" and add "grails-1.1.1" (as a "Global Library").

Done! Your project is now configured to use Grails 1.1.1 instead of Grails 1.1.

Thanks to geofflane who helped me with step #2 with his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Choose File -> Project Structure
Under Project Settings choose Modules.
Under your Module there should be a Groovy facet.
In that you can choose Add to add a new reference to your Grails installation.